# Wie heißt diese Prozedur?

Tags: word-formation

Die Prozedur, die `Wörter` oder `Wortes` in `Wort` bzw. `gesehen` oder `sah` in `seh` umwandelt, heißt [Stemming](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming).

Wie heißt die umgekehrte Prozedur, bei der die Umwandlung so verläuft:

- Substantive → Nominativ Singular, (aus `Wörter` wird `Wort`)
- Verben → Infinitiv, (aus `sah` wird `sehen`)

PS: Wenn ich mich nicht irre, ist es keine Lemmatisierung. Ich habe diesen Online-Lemmatisierer getestet: https://cst.dk/tools/index.php - laut diesem ist `Wört` das Lemma zu `Wörter`.

Comment: Did you switch from Danish to German before lemmatisation?

Comment: sure, yes, controlled it twice. Hm, weird, now it delivers `word`, like nothing happens before... Thank you for the hint. Well - it calls indeed `lemmatization`

Comment: Du meinst die Prozedur, die zur [Nennform](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nennform) führt?

Comment: @Wolf genau das, ja.

Comment: Ich denke die [Antwort von phipsgabler](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/58828/5437) bringt es weitgehend auf den Punkt. Es hat sich bislang kein zusammengesetztes Substantiv dafür etablieren können, daher wird *Bildung der Nennform* sicherlich leichter verstanden als *Nennformableitung* o.ä.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ich werde ein bisschen breiter antworten.

[Computerlinguistisch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemmatisation) würde ich *Wörter* -> *Wort* als Lemmatisierung, *Wörter* -> *Wört* als Stemming bezeichnen.  Im mir bekannten Gebrauch ist Stemming nur das Abziehen von regulärer Flexionsmorphologie, wobei das bei Ablauten im Deutschen schwammig wird -- ich würde *gesehen* -> *sah* nicht mehr als Stemming sehen, aber man könnte durchaus dafür argumentieren.  In beiden Fällen ist das Ergebnis nicht als grammatisch zu verstehen, sondern nur als Folge von Segmenten zur Repräsentation einer Äquivalenzklasse von Formen.

Die Schwierigkeit der Wahl besteht darin, wie weit man einerseits Semantik und Wortart miteinbeziehen möchte (haben *sah* und *Sicht* genug gemeinsam, um sie in eine Äquivalenzklasse zu fassen?), und andererseits in der Effizienz (sollen ein paar Duzend regulärer Ausdrücke reichen, oder brauche ich ein riesiges neuronales Netzwerk, dass ewig trainiert werden muss?).

Nicht-computerlinguistisch würde ich von der *Bildung der [Nennform](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nennform)* oder *Zitierform* sprechen. Diese Form ist eine vollständig grammatische (finit oder infinitit), und hängt von der Sprachtradition rein konventionell ab -- sie wird gebraucht, um Wörter anzuführen (sei es im gewöhnlichen Sprechen oder in Lexika; in manchen Sprachen unterscheiden sich diese zwei Formen).  Also das, wonach du gesucht hast.

Hier ein Beispiel, dass es komplizierter werden kann, ein Exkurs ins [Golf-Arabisch](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golf-Arabisch):

- *maka:tib*: Plural "Büros"; Vollform.
- *maktab*: Singular "Büro"; Grundform und Nennform des Substantivs, und Lemmatisierung.
- *maktabate:n*: Dual "zwei Bibliotheken"; Vollform.
- *maktaba*: Singular "Bibliothek"; Grundform, Nennform, und Lemmatisierung; gleichzeitig eine Art Stemming, weil die Dualendung `-te:n` abgezogen wurde.

Beide Wörter sind abgeleitet von:

- *k-t-b*: Wurzel für "schreiben"; das wäre hier das vollständige Stemming (weil durch Regeln von der Vollform ableitbar), und darunter würde man auch *maktabate:n* im Wörterbüch suchen.
- *kataba*: "er schrieb", dritte Person Singular Maskulinum des Perfekts (also plötzlich ein Verb!); Zitierform der Wurzel k-t-b, wenn man sie spricht.

Außerdem sollte man wissen, dass *kataba* und *k-t-b* ohne Vokalzeichen gleich geschrieben werden; das zeigt, dass Stemming etwas rein abstraktes ist, und die Zitierform aus praktischen Gründen sich aus irgendwelchen Formen ergeben kann.

Comment: Also wäre *Bildung der Nennform* die kurze Antwort. Der Exkurs ins Golfarabisch ist (nur für mich?) ziemlich verwirrend.

Comment: @Wolf, naja, ich wollte darauf hinaus, dass die drei Begriffe immer davon abhängen, was man damit macht. Aber natürlich schaut alles aus wie ein Nagel, wenn man einen Hammer in der Hand hat. Glaubst du es ist so verwirrend, dass ich es rausnehmen sollte?

Comment: Die Verallgemeinerung oder Verallgemeinerbarkeit des Nennform-Konzepts ist für sich genommen interessant. Vielleicht solltest du hierzu einen einleitenden Satz bringen und der Hinweis auf *dein* Golfarabisch scheint der springende Punkt. Wir wissen ja alle nur so viel wie uns nützt und insofern könnte man solche Einschränkungen als implizit voraussetzen und im Zweifelsfall nicht angeben. Ich würde dir also raten, den Exkurs als solchen auszuarbeiten und ein bisschen sachlicher zu formulieren.

Comment: Ich habe mal etwas daran gefeilt, hoffe in deinem Sinne.

Comment: Ausgezeichnet, danke!